# How to get current directory absolute path (pwd) in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have made a scala project and running some migrations. One of those is copy command:

```
COPY mls_certifications FROM '../reso_certifications/reso_1.4.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',');
```

Here is the location of this migration and the file I am trying to read:

```
-- migrations
    -- my_migration.sql

-- reso_certifications
    -- reso_1.4.csv
```

Since the COPY command requires absolute path, is there any way I can get the path to the current directory of the migration?

Comment: Are you aware that the path is **on the server**? So it will always be relative to the data directory